# Is this considered recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm very new to programming and would like to know if this code can also be considered a recursion since it calls itself. Also would like to know if this is good practice.

```
void editArr(int arr[], int arrSize){
int index;

cout << "Enter INDEX: ";
cin >> index;

if(index >= arrSize){
  cout << "INDEX is OUT OF BOUNDS" << endl;
  editArr(arr, arrSize);
}

cout << "Enter VALUE: ";
cin >> arr[index];

cout << "\n[1] Continue || [0] Exit";
cin >> choiceExit;
if(choiceExit == 1)
  editArr(arr, arrSize);

}
```

Comment: A function calling itself is the very definition of recursion.

Comment: If it's "good practice" or not depends. In this case it seems the function is using recursion instead of a loop for the "continue/exit" choice. That specific instance of recursion I would say is *bad* practice.

Comment: Wikiquote: Recursion in computer science is a method where the solution to a problem depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem (as opposed to [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration)) ([src](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29))

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd say it's definitiely not _good practice_, recursive calls are always prone to overflow the call stack.

Comment: Also, you don't need to have *direct* recursion (a function calling itself directly), you can also have *indirect* recursion. For example function `a` calls function `b` which in turn call function `a`. This is still recursion.

Comment: Just about nothing in this snippet is good practice.It contains several grave errors and recursion is one of them, though probably not the worst one.

Comment: When index is out of bounds you recurse, but when you exit it will go back to "Enter VALUE:" for the `index` that were out of bounds. Perhaps the rest of the code should have been in a `else` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm very new to programming and would like to know if this code can also be considered a recursion since it calls itself.

Yes, that's how *recursion* is defined. A function calls itself directly or indirectly.

> Also would like to know if this is good practice.

In general no. It's better to replace that code with a loop and using a stack (e.g. `std::stack`). In your case even a simple loop would work fine.

Recursive calls depend on the (limited) intrinsic call stack size, and are prone to overflow the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

The function calls itself, it is recursive.

The program will allocate a new stack frame every time the user choses to continue, as this could happen indefinitely, I would say a loop is a better choice here.

As a side note, this function is [tail recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion?rq=1) (except when an OOB index is given, then all hell breaks loose), so the compiler may well optimize out allocating the extra stack frame, personally I would not rely on that though.

Comment: "this function is tail recursive". Modulo bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it will work. Don't forget to define choiceExit as an integer at the top of the function. Note that it's not the usual way to initialize an array,recursion is a bit "heavy". Also it's important to note that you don't need to put Arraysize as a parameter as size(Arr) will give it. A while loop would be indeed much better. ChoiceExit could be a boolean by the way, as there are only two "cases" possible

Comment: "It seems it will work." For some definition of "work". "size(Arr) will give it". Not really.